# Force close using sockets and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

Hello people of stack....

Please see my class code and my LogCat below...

I am getting a force close when trying to connect. If someone could help me to figure out why it would be much appreciated.

Basically what the code is doing is:

1. Taking an IP Address from an intent.
2. Connecting to the IP with port 32
3. Then send a command, wait for response and the send another command.
4. After the 2 commands our sent I should get a response of "SNX_COM>"
5. Once the connection is established, I want the connection to stay open to send specific commands on button click.

Please help :)

```
package com.smarte.smartipcontrol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class IPControl extends Activity {

private Socket socket;
private String serverIpAddress = "com.smarte.smartipcontrol.ACTU_IP";
private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 32;
public PrintWriter out;
public BufferedReader in;
public String data;
public Object pd;


public void getModel(View view) {
    try {
        out.println("[m\r\n");
        //System.out.print("root\r\n");
        while(!in.ready());
        String textStatus = readBuffer();

    } catch(IOException e) {}
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.act_ipcontrol);


   try{   

   this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading..", "Please Wait...", true, false);
    new AsyncAction().execute();

   }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   }



private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
   protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
   try {
 InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
 socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
 out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 while (! in .ready());
 readBuffer();
 out.println("root\r\n");
 //System.out.print("root\r\n");
 while (! in .ready());
 readBuffer();
 out.println("root\r\n");
 //System.out.print("root\r\n");
 while (! in .ready());
 String msg = "";

while ( in .ready()) {
 msg = msg + (char) in .read();
}
} catch (IOException e) {}

       return null;//returns what you want to pass to the onPostExecute()
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   //resultis the data returned from doInbackground

       IPControl.this.data = result;




       if (IPControl.this.pd != null) {
           ((Dialog) IPControl.this.pd).dismiss();
       }
    }


}

private String readBuffer() throws IOException {
    String msg = "";

    while(in.ready()) {
        msg = msg + (char)in.read();
    }
    //System.out.print(msg);
    if(msg.indexOf("SNX_COM> ") != -1) return msg.substring(0, msg.indexOf("SNX_COM> "));
    else return msg;
}

}
```

Logcat.......

```
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPControl$AsyncAction.doInBackground(IPControl.java:71)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at com.smarte.smartipcontrol.IPControl$AsyncAction.doInBackground(IPControl.java:1)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-03 15:39:56.346: E/AndroidRuntime(2697):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true); in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

Comment: See my answer I believe your error is because your Socket did not initialiye properly.

Comment: Please see updated LogCat, its just not my day today...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
 InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
 socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
```

I can't find where your `serverIpAddress` is assigned, thus you get NullPointerException.

Comment: Hi Slezadav, yes you were correct. But still getting a force close. Please see updated LogCat.

Comment: Now your problem is on line 51, I guess it is this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading..", "Please Wait...", true, false); try removing it for a while.

Comment: Or even more probably your crash occurs, when you rotate your screen, because activity is getting recreated and your ProgressDialog leaks.

Comment: @ChrisJamesHancocks  Chris. It's clear that your code has multiple problems and, I suspect that you are trying to run before you can walk evidenced by your attempts to use advanced techniques when you don't know the basics. May I respectfully suggest that it is a better use of everyone's time, especially yours, for you to learn what causes a nullPointerException, how to find the exact source in logcat and how to debug and fix it. Without basic skills such as these you will continue to be frustrated and you are likely to end up with inefficient, difficult to maintain code. Good luck.

Comment: @Simon Hi Simon, yes I am definitely trying to run before I can walk. I thought I would just jump right in at the deep end and hope for the best. I am slowly getting somewhere though.

Comment: @ChrisJamesHancocks Keep at it. Best tip I can give you if you want to continue running is that every time you access something which is outside your app, which the network clearly is, you should ask "how can this fail"? and write the code to deal with the failures *first*. Then write the code you really want to write. I know that the temptation is to "see it working" but the risk it that you only do the working code and your app ships will serious bugs.  If you need help with the basics, then well constructed questions with all of the relevant information will always get a good response.